# Dynamically adjust Textview size with ImageView size when layout changes

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an ImageView and on that ImageView I have a TextView. I need to always write my text on the actual image. However when the virtual keyboard is opened and layout is changed, the width of the image inside ImageView becomes smaller (it already doesn't occupy the entire width of the phone screen) to keep aspect ratio, as a result my text is written out of the bound of the image. 
Can anyone help me how can I get the actual image size when the layout is changed, so that I can accordingly adjust the size of Textview. I have tried to use onLayoutChangeListener, but for some reason that callback gives smaller newHeight, but the width is the same as before, although I can see on my phone screen that image width has become smaller and does not fit in the entire width of the phone screen.

Comment: use ImageView.getImageMatrix() together with IV.gerDrawable()

Comment: or you can use LayerDrawable to stack two or more Drawables one on top of another

Answer (score 0):

In layout file just set **layout_alignLeft** and **layout_alignRight** params for your TextView like this

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/YourImageView"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/YourImageView"
```

Answer (score 0):

this library is might be useful  to you :)

> https://code.google.com/p/android-flowtextview/

[image]